# ¿Cómo enviar el valor de una variable proveniente de un componente y recibirlo en otro componente? Angular / Ionic 4-5

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, ionic-framework

Quiero enviar el valor de una variable para posteriormente utilizarlo en otro componente. Pero al momento que imprimo ese valor traído desde un servicio, en la consola me aparece 'undefined'

Esta es el componente de donde quiero mandar el valor de la variable 'message' y su valor 'Hola desde home'

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareService } from '../share.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  message: any;

  constructor( private shareSvc: ShareService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.shareSvc.sharedMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)

    this.message = 'Hola desde home';
   
    this.shareSvc.varService = this.message;

  }
  
}
```

Este es mi servicio, donde solamente estoy declarando la variable varService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareService {
  // private message = new BehaviorSubject<any> (null) ;
  // sharedMessage = this.message.asObservable();
  public varService : any;

  constructor() { }

  // nextMessage(message: string) {
  //   this.message.next(message)
  // }
}
```

Y esta es el componente donde quiero obtener el valor traído desde home.ts y utilizando el servicio como intermediario

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareService } from '../share.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagina2',
  templateUrl: './pagina2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagina2.page.scss'],
})
export class Pagina2Page implements OnInit {

  

  constructor( private shareSvc: ShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.shareSvc.varService);
    // this.shareSvc.sharedMessage.subscribe(message => {
    //   this.message = message;
    // });
    // this.newMessage();

  }

  // newMessage() {
  //   this.shareSvc.nextMessage("I am from page 2")
  // }


}
```

Comment: Estás habriendo page2 desde la ruta directamente? es decir, estás poniendo en el navegador http://localhost:8100/pagina2?

Ten en cuenta que el componente home se tiene que cargar para dar valor al service.

Comment: Cómo llegas hasta page2? Debes cargar el componente home para que conecte con el servicio y éste a page2.

Comment: Haz tu `varService` `static`. La instancia de `ShareService` que se inyecta en un componente no es la misma que del otro.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer esto con el componente que recibe el valor

```
export class Pagina2Page implements OnInit {

  message: any = false;

  constructor( private shareSvc: ShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shareSvc.sharedMessage.subscribe(message => {
      this.message = message;
     });
    
    console.log(this.message);
    
  }

}
```

si de ese modo te devuelve false, es que no esta almacenando el valor del primer componente, deberias entonces intentar usar una funcion implementando el patron singleton ([Singleton Typescript](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/singleton-made-easy-with-typescript-6ad55a7ba7ff))